# Why use "ex post facto" when "post facto" means the same thing?

Tags: latin, redundancy

In legal language I have come across the term "ex post facto".  Isn't "ex" redundant in this phrase? "post facto" also means "after the fact", so it should be sufficient.

This is commonly used in English, especially in legal documents as I mentioned above.  If we began to remove all words in the English language that came from other sources, we could probably halve the dictionary.

Comment: [*A Dictionary of Modern Legal Usage*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=35dZpfMmxqsC&pg=PA342&dq=%22ex+post+facto%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22ex%20post%20facto%22&f=false) mentions this when discussing what even they call a *slightly pompous but fairly common* usage. ***Ex post** for **ex post facto** is an odd ellipsis without literary legitimacy ... Yet another strange shortening is **post facto***. But this is really about ***Latin***, not English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Latin, not English

Comment: @FumbleFingers - OP is asking why in English the expression is used in that form.

Comment: @Josh61: I can see that. But since the only meaningful answer nets down to *because it was used in Latin in that form, and it **is** Latin*, I think it's Off Topic.

Comment: Among other things, the US Constitution explicitly forbids "ex post facto" laws, and that is the only (or almost certainly earliest) exposure that many folks have to the term.  The term is also a term of law in England and elsewhere.

Comment: @FumbleFingers both Fumble and Finger are derived from very similar German and Dutch words. :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd like you to "unclose" this question although it has been answered.  It is certainly a question about English.  Note the other comments (including your own and by @hot-licks) that are referring to modern daily usage in English.  Surely you don't think the US constitution is written in Latin?

Comment: @Chiwda: Sure, the US Constitution and many other "legal documents" include the term, ***ex post facto***. But this is a site dedicated to *English* usage - within which context it's not really relevant to ask why some specific *Latin* expression includes an element that you think is "redundant".

Comment: The point is that the _Latin_ expression is currently _only_ used in the English language.  The other point is that no one else seems to agree strongly with you.  Someone even _answered_ the question.

Comment: This question should be re-opened because it's a legitimate English question.  I am writing a witness statement for the police, and I need to say that a defendant did something after the alleged crime ("ex post facto"). The problem is, "ex post facto" in its typical usage, refers to laws enacted retroactively to govern the past. Perhaps the better term is "post facto"? Now we will never know, because you closed the question! >.<

Comment: @FumbleFingers this question has now earned the "Famous Question" badge.  At least now you should reopen it!

Comment: @Chiwda: Just because I was the *first* to closevote doesn't mean I have special powers to reopen it, even if I wanted to (and I haven't changed my mind anyway). I'm just an ordinary user with 1 vote on such matters. If you want to persuade someone to reconsider, ask tchrist - he's now a mod, so he could reopen it unilaterally. But although I don't like to preempt his current position, I doubt tchrist will have shifted either.

Comment: @tchrist please consider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being a Latin locution, it must be used as such, ***ex***  means ***from***:

[Ex post facto](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ex+post+facto):

> - from or by subsequent action; subsequently; retrospectively; retroactively.

Word Origin:

> - from Latin ***ex (from)***; + ***post (afterwards)*** + ***factus (done),*** from facere to do

[Ex post facto](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ex%20post%20facto&allowed_in_frame=0): (Etymonline):

> - from Medieval Latin ex postfacto, "from what is done afterwards." From facto, ablative of factum "deed, act".

Comment: I always thought ex meant after based on a naive assumption.  Thanx @josh61 for clearing that up!

Comment: Hit it by accident.

Comment: Does this mean the usage without ex is wrong? I often see people using just post facto, eg. Post facto approval, instead of ex post facto approval